# Не работает страница поиска с номером >200 | Search page number >200 is bugged

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, поиск

При попытке перехода на страницу результатов поиска с номером >200 выводит "0 результатов", даже если страниц действительно больше 200. Например

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=200&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=помогите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=200&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5) - работает
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=201&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=помогите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=201&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5) - нет результатов
хотя на этот запрос 217 страниц результатов

**UPD:** Граница в 200 страниц - если выбрано 50 элементов на страницу. Если выбрать меньше, граница соответственно будет больше.

---

Trying to open search results' page number >200 displays "0 results", even for the query that actually returns >200 result pages. For example

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=200&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=помогите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=200&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5) - works
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=201&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=помогите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?page=201&tab=Newest&pagesize=50&q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5) - says no results
despite this query actually has 217 pages of results

**UPD:** The 200-page borderline is for 50 elements per page. If less elements per page is chosen, the borderline becomes bigger.

Comment: Надо в заголовок написать "помогите, не работает поиск" :)

Comment: А на so такого нету? Если есть, то на метамету лучше постить...

Comment: @pavel по моим тестам, на en so не воспроизводится: https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1000&tab=Newest&q=help - работает

Comment: @pavel там не пишут "помогите" так часто

Comment: Судя по всему, тут срабатывает ограничение в 10000 элементов, которое однако не пропихнуто в итоговое кол-во страниц.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибку пофиксили. См. баг репорт на MSE: [No more than 10,000 results are visible in search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303174/339911)